# Reset a slide button with a select option

Tags: jquery, html, css

How do I reset my buton to the YES position (green color) if I chosse or I change an option?
My jquery code does not work. Currently the style of my button disappearing.
I don't think the solution is very complicated, but I don't have enough jquery knowledge to solve this problem.
Thank !

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPrEt.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3ywj.jpg)

```js
    $('#select').on('change', function(e) {
      $('#button').toggleClass('onoff');
      e.preventDefault();
    });
```

```css
.onoff {
  margin-left: -27px;
  display: -moz-inline-stack;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  *vertical-align: auto;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 55px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.onoff label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 240%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #900;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: normal; 
  color: #FFF;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s, text-indent 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s, text-indent 0.3s;
  -o-transition: background 0.3s, text-indent 0.3s;
  transition: background 0.3s, text-indent 0.3s;
  text-indent: 27px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
}
.onoff label:after {
  content: 'NO';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 14px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 12px; 
  color: #FFF;
 
  z-index: 1;
}
.onoff label:before {
  content: ''; 
  width: 15px;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #FFF; 
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: left 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: left 0.3s;
  -o-transition: left 0.3s;
  transition: left 0.3s;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.onoff input:checked + label {
  background: #378b2c; 
  text-indent: 8px;
}
.onoff input:checked + label:after {
  content: 'YES';
  color: #FFF; 
  left: 14px;
  font-size: 14px; 
}
.onoff input:checked + label:before {
  left: 114px;
}
input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio] {
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -5px;
}
input[type=radio] {
    bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="button" class="onoff" style="margin-left:100px">
<input type="checkbox" id="tool_closed_onoff" name="tool_closed_onoff" style="width:20px; height:20px;" />
<label for="tool_closed_onoff" /></label>
</div>

<br /><br />

<div id="select" style="margin-left:100px">
<select>
  <option value="No option" selected="selected">No option</option>
  <option value="option1">option1</option>
  <option value="option2">option2</option>
  <option value="option3">option3</option>
  <option value="option4">option4</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to set the checked property of input to true

```js
$('#select').on('change', function(e) {
      $('#tool_closed_onoff').prop('checked',true);
      e.preventDefault();
    });
```

```css
.onoff {
  margin-left: -27px;
  display: -moz-inline-stack;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  *vertical-align: auto;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 55px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.onoff label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 240%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #900;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: normal; 
  color: #FFF;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s, text-indent 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s, text-indent 0.3s;
  -o-transition: background 0.3s, text-indent 0.3s;
  transition: background 0.3s, text-indent 0.3s;
  text-indent: 27px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
}
.onoff label:after {
  content: 'NO';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 14px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 12px; 
  color: #FFF;
 
  z-index: 1;
}
.onoff label:before {
  content: ''; 
  width: 15px;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #FFF; 
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: left 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: left 0.3s;
  -o-transition: left 0.3s;
  transition: left 0.3s;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.onoff input:checked + label {
  background: #378b2c; 
  text-indent: 8px;
}
.onoff input:checked + label:after {
  content: 'YES';
  color: #FFF; 
  left: 14px;
  font-size: 14px; 
}
.onoff input:checked + label:before {
  left: 114px;
}
input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio] {
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -5px;
}
input[type=radio] {
    bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="button" class="onoff" style="margin-left:100px">
<input type="checkbox" id="tool_closed_onoff" name="tool_closed_onoff" style="width:20px; height:20px;" />
<label for="tool_closed_onoff" /></label>
</div>

<br /><br />

<div id="select" style="margin-left:100px">
<select>
  <option value="No option" selected="selected">No option</option>
  <option value="option1">option1</option>
  <option value="option2">option2</option>
  <option value="option3">option3</option>
  <option value="option4">option4</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. And to use the reverse color, just put False.
Great !!!

Comment: Answer is incomplete, if you change your mind, and select 'No option' the switch never gets reset back to 'No'

Comment: I guess the author had problem about changing the checked status of the checkbox & not about the condition of selection, so I just did that, but I'd be glad to help if author wants a solution for just the selection of values

Answer (score 0):

You have a if/else statement since you would be toggling on/off if you jump from option 2/3 (which, if I understood) would result in incorrect switching to yes

see demo

```js
$('select').on('change', function(e) {

  if ($(this).val() === 'No option') {
    $("#tool_closed_onoff").prop('checked', false);
  } else {
    $("#tool_closed_onoff").prop('checked', true);
  }
});
```

```css
.onoff {
  margin-left: -27px;
  display: -moz-inline-stack;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  *vertical-align: auto;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 55px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.onoff label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 240%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #900;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #FFF;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s, text-indent 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s, text-indent 0.3s;
  -o-transition: background 0.3s, text-indent 0.3s;
  transition: background 0.3s, text-indent 0.3s;
  text-indent: 27px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
}

.onoff label:after {
  content: 'NO';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 14px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #FFF;
  z-index: 1;
}

.onoff label:before {
  content: '';
  width: 15px;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: left 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: left 0.3s;
  -o-transition: left 0.3s;
  transition: left 0.3s;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.onoff input:checked+label {
  background: #378b2c;
  text-indent: 8px;
}

.onoff input:checked+label:after {
  content: 'YES';
  color: #FFF;
  left: 14px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.onoff input:checked+label:before {
  left: 114px;
}

input[type=checkbox],
input[type=radio] {
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -5px;
}

input[type=radio] {
  bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="button" class="onoff" style="margin-left:100px">
  <input type="checkbox" id="tool_closed_onoff" name="tool_closed_onoff" style="width:20px; height:20px;" />
  <label for="tool_closed_onoff" />
</div>

<br /><br />

<div id="select" style="margin-left:100px">
  <select>
    <option value="No option" selected="selected">No option</option>
    <option value="option1">option1</option>
    <option value="option2">option2</option>
    <option value="option3">option3</option>
    <option value="option4">option4</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you blurfus,
The idea was that the "No option" option is only visible when the page first loads.
If you choose an option, the button keeps its first position "NO".
If you change the position of the button to "YES", but then decide to change the option, the button must return to its first position "NO"  by default.
Thank you for this second solution which will surely help me for another syntax.

Comment: @CantaVero but the selected answer never returns to NO.  Once changed to a YES position, it does not return to NO (no matter what the selection is)

Comment: In my project,  my form input sends a URL who refreshes the page.

Comment: Is the assumption then, that the user never selects the wrong option by mistake then!?

Comment: This is just one in a series of choices.